# Remove numbers from end of string if count of numbers(characters) > 8

Tags: excel, regex, vba

[image]

I need to remove numbers from end of string if count of numbers(characters) > 8 
I have used the below functions , but it remove all numbers from the string. 
So, How this function can be modified to add a condition `if count of numbers(characters) > 8` 
In advance, grateful for any helpful comments and answers.

```
Option Explicit
 
Function StripNumber(stdText As String)
  Dim str As String, i As Integer
 
    stdText = Trim(stdText)
 
    For i = 1 To Len(stdText)
        If Not IsNumeric(Mid(stdText, i, 1)) Then
            str = str & Mid(stdText, i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
        StripNumber = str ' * 1
End Function
 
Function Remove_Number(Text As String) As String
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
      .Global = True
      .Pattern = "[0-9]"
      Remove_Number = .Replace(Text, "")
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Do you mean if the number of trailing digits is > 8? what's the expected result for `File-abc1234567.doc`?

Comment: @Nick ,`File-abc1234567.doc`

Comment: Then Wiktor's answer should work for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
\d{8,}(?=\.\w+$)
\d{8,}(?=\.[^.]+$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sahR5S/1). If there must be at least 9 digits, replace 8 with 9.

*Details*:

- `\d{8,}` - eight or more digits
- `(?=\.\w+$)` - that are immediately followed with a `.` and one or more word chars and then end of string must follow
- `(?=\.[^.]+$)` - the eight or more digits must be immediately followed with a `.` char and then one or more chars other than a `.` char till the end of string.

Comment: I have used like this and works , but is this the correct syntax
`.Pattern = "[0-9]\d{8,}(?=\.\w+$)"
.Pattern = "\d{8,}(?=\.[^.]+$)"`

Comment: @Leedo Use as is: `.Pattern = "\d{8,}(?=\.\w+$)"`

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the newest functions you can avoid VBA alltogether:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=LET(X,TEXTBEFORE(A2,".",-1),Y,TEXTAFTER(A2,X),Z,TEXTAFTER(CONCAT(".",IFERROR(--MID(X,SEQUENCE(LEN(X)),1),".")),".",-1),IF(LEN(Z)>8,SUBSTITUTE(A2,Z&Y,Y),A2))
```

Or, if there are no leading zeros in these numbers:

```
=LET(X,TEXTBEFORE(A2,".",-1),Y,TEXTAFTER(A2,X),Z,MAX(IFERROR(--MID(X,SEQUENCE(LEN(X)),LEN(X)),"")),IF(LEN(Z)>8,SUBSTITUTE(A2,Z&Y,Y),A2))
```

---

Or; a spilled array:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=BYROW(A2:A6,LAMBDA(a,LET(X,TEXTBEFORE(a,".",-1),Y,TEXTAFTER(a,X),Z,TEXTAFTER(CONCAT(".",IFERROR(--MID(X,SEQUENCE(LEN(X)),1),".")),".",-1),IF(LEN(Z)>8,SUBSTITUTE(a,Z&Y,Y),a))))
```

Or:

```
=BYROW(A2:A6,LAMBDA(a,LET(X,TEXTBEFORE(a,".",-1),Y,TEXTAFTER(a,X),Z,MAX(IFERROR(--MID(X,SEQUENCE(LEN(X)),LEN(X)),"")),IF(LEN(Z)>8,SUBSTITUTE(a,Z&Y,Y),a))))
```

Comment: OMG, 4 solutions for a single query, really amazing sir!

Comment: Unfortunately I have office 2016, So neither any one from your formulas is applicable.