# Pass of `ByVal` argument to Regex function leads to very slow code , although using Array

Tags: arrays, excel, regex, vba

I am using this `Regex function` to (Remove numeric characters from end of string if count of numbers >= 9),

```
Function Remove_Number_Regex(Text As String) As String
'Remove numbers from end of string if count of numbers(characters) >= 9
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
      .Global = True
      .Pattern = "\d{9,}(?=\.\w+$)"
      Remove_Number_Regex = .Replace(Text, "")
    End With
End Function
```

I tried on excel (as formula) and it works as it should without any error. 
Then I used it inside vba using Array , but I got this error

> Compile error: ByRef argument type mismatch

I fixed that error by passing **ByVal argument** to the declaration of Regex function

```
Function Remove_Number_Regex(ByVal Text As String) As String
```

And that leads to a very slow code to finish 18 seconds on (10K row) ,although using any other text function inside the same array takes 0.4 seconds to finish. 
In advance, grateful for any helpful comments and answers.

```
Sub Use_Function_Remove_Number_Regex()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 
    Dim arg As Range, arr
 
    With ActiveSheet
        Set arg = .Range("O1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp)) '10k rows
    End With
 
    arr = arg.value
 
    Dim r As Long, j As Long
 
   For j = 1 To 4
     For r = 1 To UBound(arr)
          arr(r, j) = Remove_Number_Regex(arr(r, j))
      Next r
    Next j
 
    arg.value = arr
 
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: Speculation, but it seems likely the regex compiler used here is none too fast, especially if you're bouncing through ActiveX/IDispatch/whatever the proper term is. Try creating the relevant `RegExp` object only once and reusing it for the entirety of the calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking; using regular expressions will slow things down. You are correct that common string-operations are faster. So, why not use them:

```
Function Remove_Number(Text As String) As String

Dim nr As String: nr = CStr(Val("1" & StrReverse(Split(Text, ".")(0))))

If Len(nr) > 9 Then
    Remove_Number = Replace(Text, StrReverse(Mid(nr, 2)) & ".", ".")
Else
    Remove_Number = Text
End If

End Function
```

To test this function based on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72182176/9758194):

```
Sub Test()

Dim arr As Variant: arr = Array("Anomaly - allhelipads1335023398818.doc", "Anomaly - oilpipingW8.doc")

For Each el In arr
    Debug.Print Remove_Number(CStr(el))
Next

End Sub
```

Returns:

[image]

---

The trick used:

- Split your input based on the dot, and return the 1st element from the array (zero based);
- Reverse the string;
- Extract the numeric value when concatenated with a '1' (to prevent trailing zeros to disappear);
- Check if length is more than 9 (accounting for the '1') and if so replace the value accordingly.

---

**Note:** Depending on your version of Excel, you could just stay away from VBA alltogether. See my answer to your previous question.

Comment: First, I have office 2016, so I have to use udf.
I tried your answer on excel formula then it works as it should, **But** when I tried inside my vba array I got again
`Compile error: ByRef argument type mismatch` and when I added `ByVal` argument to the function and run code then I got this error
(Subscript out of range) @ this part of your function `nr = CStr(Val("1" & StrReverse(Split(Text, ".")(0))))`

Comment: @Leedo, I have no plans of fixing my working code. However, what I think you are facing is that the elements of the array are not of the type "string". Therefor a mismatch occurs. Do you pass numeric data of type integer or double for example? Note how I used `CStr()` when I called the function.

Comment: I figured out , there are some blank cells on my range, that's why when I added ByVal argument to the function and run code then I got this error (`Subscript out of range`) .kindly this issue should be fixed on my array or on your function?

Comment: You might want to fix that in your loop of your array. Check if string is empty, then empty. If not empty then invoke the function @Leedo.